# How to handle bytes in java properly?

Tags: java, byte

I want to make a hex to base64 converter. But I want to make it extendable, so it can convert to bytes from all formats and vice versa. Later I might want to XOR bytes or just random access any specific bits.

The problem is that bytes in java are signed data types and they behave differently from int's. If I do a >> operator for example, it won't actually shift the bits for negative numbers.

How do you handle that in java? I know I can use InputStream and OutputStream, but I still don't know what to do the resulting bytes.

Comment: int unsignedInt = Byte.toUnsignedInt(myByte); handles your signed byte problem.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. `>>` *will* shift bytes, but you'd need to mask with `&0x7f` to clear the extra bit, assuming you want to 0-pad.

Comment: Have a look at this library and its `ByteString` class: https://github.com/square/okio#okio

Comment: It's a very broad question, probably too broad to be well suited for the Stackoverflow format.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson it worked!

Comment: @JonSkeet I just wanted to extract the 4 upper bits, but it turned out that byte doesn't work exactly the way I thought. Yeah, I was looking for something like that.